# How do I dynamically create a WordPress menu?

Tags: wordpress

I have searched and searched and there is a post that shows that I can create pages and it has a spot to add the page to a menu.  I would like to create a custom menu with parents and children.  Is this possible in WordPress?

Comment: I'd start by reading the documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus. This question is way too broad without a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very possible, but there are a few things that you need to do.

**1, Register a menu**

This involves adding some lines of code to your functions.php file (in your theme):

```
function register_menu(){
    register_nav_menu('menu','Header Navigation');
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_menu' );
```

The code above essentially creates a new menu object in the database for use. Once the object has been created you can then create as many objects as you want (through the WordPress UI) without registering new menus through the code. It's almost like an activation code.

**2, Create the menu**

Once the above code is added, you will be able to access the "menus" section in WordPress. This is located in the left hand column under the "Appearance" drop down.

Follow the step to create your menu. You can now create multiple menus (if you need), and each menu allows you to create parent and children (sub-navigation) if needed.

**3, Add the menu to your site**

Once the menu has been created you need to get the ID of the menu. This can usually be found in the URL and will read something like `wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=11`.

Once you have the ID you can drop that menu into your site. It can be as easy as: `wp_nav_menu( array(11) )` whereas I'm using the menu ID from before.

codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Or you can get more technical and get all of the menu items to create your own custom navigation using your own HTML:

`$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items(11);`

codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items

Hope this points you in the right direction!

Comment: I am sorry it took so long for me to get back to this question.  I would like more clarification to step number 2.  Adding Items to the menu.  I need to add 311 items to the menu.  They are coming in from a tab delimited file where column 1 is the product line and column 2 is the product item.  The documentation doesn't seem to be clear on this point or of course I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: This answers works on the assumption that all of your pages exist inside of wordpress. You would need to create pages for all of your products before hand.

Comment: It seems that there is an easy way to do what I was looking for.  "Automatically add new pages to a menu."